# Can I add many to one mapping in Embeddable class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, hibernate-mapping

Can I add many to one mapping in Embeddable class.
Here it is trying to fetch the value jobCategoryMast direclty. 
which is a mapping object.

throws exception  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column jobvaccina0_.jobcategorymast does not exist

```
@Entity
@Table(name="job_vac",schema="cis")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JobVacc implements java.io.Serializable {


    // Fields    
     @Column(name="default", length=1)
     private String default;

     @EmbeddedId
     private JobVaccPK jobVaccinationPK;

     public JobVacc(){

     }
     //getters and setters
     }
```

// JobVaccPK  class

```
@Embeddable
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JobVaccPK implements Serializable{

    /*@Column(name = "job_category_id")
    private Long jobCategoryId;*/
    private JobCategoryMast jobCategoryMast;

    @Column(name = "vaccination_id")
    private Long vaccId;


    @Column(name = "screening_type_id")
    private Long screeningTypeId;


    /**
     * @return the jobCategoryMast
     */
    public JobCategoryMast getJobCategoryMast() {
        return jobCategoryMast;
    }

    /**
     * @param jobCategoryMast the jobCategoryMast to set
     */
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="job_category_id")
    public void setJobCategoryMast(JobCategoryMast jobCategoryMast) {
        this.jobCategoryMast = jobCategoryMast;
    }
    //other setters and getters
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [JPA 2.0 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf):

> Relationship mappings defined within an embedded id class are not supported.

although maybe your JPA provider could support it.